# PostgreSQL moving database with functions

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

I have strange problem.

I tried to move database from one server to another using pgAdmin III.
Database was created on server with PostgreSQL 8.4.9 and I wanted to move it on second server with PostgreSQL 8.2.11.
To do It, I used "backup" option and saved file, after that I used "restore" option on new database. Tables are loaded but there aren't any functions in new database.

Maybe it is because of different postgreSQL versions?

Does anyone know the reason? Any solution?

Comment: Are you sure it's 8.4.9 to 8.2.11 as you shouldn't use 8.2.x anymore. Also there have been a lot of changes between 8.2 -> 8.4 which most likely will cause you to revisit your function to backport them

Comment: I don't think you can downgrade like that. And both versions are no longer supported anyway. You should really upgrade to a 9.x version.

Comment: Yes,  I'm pretty sure, it wasn't my choice, it is The Only Possibility... Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the functions aren't around, double-check that plpgsql is available as a language. It's available by default nowadays, but making it available used to require a [create language statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createlanguage.html).

That said, I'd echo the comments: you really should be *upgrading* to a 9.x Postgres version that is still supported, rather than downgrading from an unsupported version to one that is even older.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to do it via `pg_dump` from an interactive session and export the complete database to one ore more sql files. There you can use the `-s` switch to have only the schema which should include created functions. Having this SQL file, you can also easier backport your changes or debug if something not applying to the old fallow.